# my mobile menu is not working in all my pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me with my code I have added in js fiddle

I have added it in js fiddle..Can you please check once and let me know

I have added my css,Please check once and let me know where the problem really occurs
As I have separated my `header.php` file and included in all pages
but only the horizontal lines are showing in mobile and while clicking on it, nothing happens.
Here is my code (in dropdown I have written the same with my content)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Best Hair Transplant Clinic in Hyderabad, Vijayawada and Bangalore</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="description" content="GA Digital Solutions">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap-4.1.2/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="plugins/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/owl.theme.default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="plugins/OwlCarousel2-2.2.1/animate.css">
 <link href="plugins/jquery-datepicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main_styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/responsive.css">
</head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}     .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #ffffff;}
  .icon-bar {
    position: fixed;
   top: 60%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
 }         .icon-bar a {
   display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
 }     .icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  }

        <header class="header trans_400" style="height:140px">

        <div class="header_content d-flex flex-row align-items-center jusity-content-start trans_400">

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.php">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>





        <!-- Main Navigation -->
        <nav class="main_nav"  style="margin-top:50px">
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                <!--<li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a>             </li>-->
                <li class=""><a href="index.php">HOME</a>               </li>
                <li><a href="about-us.php">ABOUT US</a></li>


                <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="hair-transplant-in-india.php"><?php echo strtoupper("Hair Transplant");?></a>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="fue-hair-transplant.php">FUE Hair Transplant</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="fut-hair-transplant.php">FUT Hair Transplant</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="hair-transplant-in-india.php">Hair Replacement</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="prp-hair-treatment.php">PRP Hair Treatment</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="hair-loss-treatment-in-india.php">Hair Loss Treatment</a>
                   <a class="dropdown-item" href="laser-hair-therapy.php">Lase Hair Therapy</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="hair-extensions.php">Hair Extensions</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="laser-hair-comb.php">Laser Hair Comb</a>

  </div>
 </div>

                <li><a href="results.php">OUR RESULTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.php">BLOGS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT </a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="header_extra d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-end ml-auto">



            <!-- Appointment Button -->
            <div class="button button_1 header_button" style="margin-top:45px"><a href="get-free-consultation.php">Get a Consultation</a></div>

            <!-- Header Social -->
            <div class="" style="margin-top:40px">
                <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-start">
                    <li><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=918019012307&amp;text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20services" target="_blank"><img src="images/whatsapp.png" height="40px" width="40px" style="margin-top:12px"></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Hamburger -->
            <div class="hamburger"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="icon-bar" style="padding-left:1300px">
            <a href="#phonecall" class="phone">
                <i class="fa fa-phone">

                </i>
                </a>
```

```
</div>

    </header>
```

Comment: We need your entire code (CSS, JS...). Without this, it is very difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: Where is the body?

Comment: If you set up your code on https://jsfiddle.net we can have a play with it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalithanaraharisetty/6rgmdv07/3/